# How to export some rows of a MySQL table from a WHERE clause?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

How to export some rows of a MySQL table with where clause from a PHP script?

I have a MySQL say test and I want to create a importable .sql file for rows where id are between 10 and 100, using PHP script.

I want to create a sql file say test.sql which can be imported to MySQL database.

Mycode:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root","","mydatabase");

$tableName  = 'test';
$backupFile = '/opt/lampp/htdocs/practices/phpTest/test.sql';
$query      = "SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '$backupFile' FROM $tableName WHERE id BETWEEN 10 AND 500";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
```

This creates a test.sql file, but when I try to import, it gives error #1064.
My script only creates a file with rows with columns name and table sturcute or insert query.

Comment: Is it absolutely necessary to do that from php? Is it a possibility to to use `mysqldump`?

Comment: Unless you want to build the insert statements yourself I don't believe this is possible.

Comment: You could exec out to mysqldump though

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments you can use mysqldump the following way.

```
mysqldump --user=... --password=... --host=... DB_NAME --where=<YOUR CLAUSE> > /path/to/output/file.sql
```

If you want this to be in your php file you can do the following

```
exec('mysqldump --user=... --password=... --host=... DB_NAME --where=<YOUR CLAUSE> > /path/to/output/file.sql');
```

Comment: exec('mysqldump --user=root --password= --host=localhost mytest test --where=<WHERE id BETWEEN 10 AND 500> > /opt/lampp/htdocs/practices/phpTest/test.sql');
I does not work. Am I write it right. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: exec('mysqldump --user=root --password= --host=localhost mytest test --where="id BETWEEN 10 AND 500" > /opt/lampp/htdocs/practices/phpTest/test.sql');

Comment: it creates a black file. Nothing in the file.

Comment: Can you check the query in the WHERE CLAUSE, the following links will guide you through http://www.electrictoolbox.com/mysqldump-selectively-dump-data/ and http://www.it-iss.com/mysql/mysql-mysqldump-where-clause/

Comment: It's working for one example I posted but don't work if I use below:
exec('mysqldump -t --user=root --password= --host=localhost mytest test --where="id IN (SELECT st_id from state WHERE std_id BETWEEN 145000 AND 150769) " > /opt/lampp/htdocs/practices/phpTest/fb_posts.sql');

Answer (score 12):

In very simply way go to your phpMyAdmin 
select you database whose particular rows you want to export
click on "SQL" (To Run SQL query/queries on database)
Write sql query and execute it 
Like select * from test table limit 500 now what ever result come 
Just at the bottom see "Query results operations"
just click on  **Export**

All done :-)

Comment: that's perfect! didn't know that - or at least forgot about this possibility. this is the simplest way when using phpmyadmin!

Comment: thats the simplest solution

Comment: I can't find the button "Query results operations". Note : I have v4.2.1.

Comment: "Query results operations" is a section when you run any query in phpmyadmin

Just below the query result you can see

Query results operations: 

Print view 
Export <---- I am talking about it 
Display chart Create view

Comment: This however doesn't let you export data in sql format when you use joins!

Comment: Exactly What I needed. Side Note: even if you are being redirected over to Export tab with nothing in view, just proceed with the export and the dump will have the relevant Rows. At first I got confused as whether it was gonna export the whole DB.

Comment: in MySQ: Workbench 8.0 (on Windows 10),exporting the results of a query defaults to exporting it as a csv. But, when typing in the name of the file to save, if you change the "Save as type" from ".csv" to "sql" and click OK, then when the dialog returns you to MySQL, it then asks you to select the name of the table (for Insert statements), then generates/saves a SQL file instead. It is an unintuitive UI, that at first seems like there is no way to generate export using INSERT statements. But this is how it's done. Workbench should instead ask upfront about format, then let you name the file.

Answer (score 3):

Mysql Shell command

```
mysqldump -u user -p password -h host Database Table --where="Condition"> /path/exportFile.sql
```

Example

```
mysqldump -u user -p 123456 -h host Database Student --where="age > 10"> /path/exportFile.sql
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have exported data using OUTFILE then you have to import it using INFILE COMMAND

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root","","mydatabase");

$tableName  = 'test';
$backupFile = '/opt/lampp/htdocs/practices/phpTest/test.sql';
$query      = "LOAD DATA INFILE '$backupFile' INTO TABLE $tableName";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
```

OR you can make csv file using

```
 $con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root","","mydatabase");
 $tableName  = 'test';
 $backupFile = '/opt/lampp/htdocs/practices/phpTest/test.sql';
 $query      = 'SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '."'$backupFile'".'
                FIELDS TERMINATED BY "," OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '.'\'"\'
                LINES TERMINATED BY \'\n\'
                FROM '.$tableName.' WHERE id BETWEEN 10 AND 500';

 $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
```

and then import this file.

Hope this works...

Comment: I don't want to load from php. I want to load using phpmyadmin but export from php

Comment: $query = 'SELECT * INTO OUTFILE'. $backupFile.'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY'. ','.' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY'. '"'.
'LINES TERMINATED BY'. '\n'.
'FROM '.$tableName.' WHERE id BETWEEN 10 AND 500';
but it creates nothing.

Comment: I have edited the query... please recheck and be sure You have are using the right path .. I have used it and it works perfectly ...

Comment: Check for right permissions in folder /opt/lampp/htdocs/practices/phpTest