# how to mysqldump last 10 rows for EVERY TABLE in a database?

Tags: database, export, mysql, database-backups

got a lot of articles about how to mysqldump last 'n' rows from a table in a database. for example `mysqldump --user=superman --password=batman --host=gothamcity.rds.com --where="1=1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10" DB_NAME TABLE_NAME ./path/to/dump/file.sql` as found from these answers in [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15287424/636762) and [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/a/180630/127202)

But, how do i tell mysqldump to export last 'n' rows for EVERY TABLE in a database

Answer (score 4):

Here is what i did in the terminal. The idea is to basically get a list of all tablenames, and then pipe that list of tablenames into a while loop in bash where each of those tables are dumped into a separate dumpfile (named by the tablename) individually.

`mysql --user=superman --password=batman --host=gothamcity.rds.com --port=3306 --database=jokersDB --execute="show tables" --silent --batch | while read tablename ; do mysqldump --user=superman --password=batman --host=gothamcity.rds.com --port=3306 --where="1=1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10" jokersDB $tablename --add-drop-table > $tablename.sql ; done`

It worked. Only issue is, it dumped each table into it's own individual SQL file - not all tables were dumped to a single file. But i guess the contents of those individual files could also be joined together into a single file via some other bash commands.

Answer (score 2):

Addition to [solution of @Syed Rakid Al Hasan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33844469/10051497)

If we change mysqldump writing part little bit like this

> > $tablename.sql

into

> >> jokersDB.sql

we can dump all database data with offset 10 in single file

Full command:

> mysql --user=superman --password=batman --host=gothamcity.rds.com --port=3306 --database=jokersDB --execute="show tables" --silent --batch | while read tablename ; do mysqldump --user=superman --password=batman --host=gothamcity.rds.com --port=3306 --where="1=1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10" jokersDB $tablename --add-drop-table **>> jokersDB.sql** ; done

**jokersDB.sql file must be present and empty**

Comment: What if, I also want to get relationships with each of those rows, how would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `--where` flag with multiple tables as long as it makes sense syntactically for each of the tables. So if all of your tables have a surrogate PK column called `id`, then you don't need to name any tables at all. Just dump with the `--all-databases` flag (or name the database you want) and your `--where` flag with the ORDER BY/LIMIT specified.

> mysqldump --user=superman --password=batman --host=gothamcity.rds.com --where="1=1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10" --databases DB_NAME > /path/to/dump/file.sql