# Test aplication with database on pre-productioon

Tags: php, testing

I have a app written in php and I have a very large DB (3Tbyte) on production status.

I wish to start to write php test but I don't wish to use the production database in order don't pollute the production DB.

I have a pre-production way with very small database (1G), I have the possibility to increase the dimension, in order to arrive the same size of the prod (but the cost is not cheap).

I wish to know that there are some good practices in order to do it, like for example to import some datas from prod to pre-prod or whatever else.

Comment: Why not use transactions to not change anything in the database? Why not use fixtures to use a completely different system that you can cleanly setup from scratch before each test run?

Comment: I cannot use the transactions because I need to test them. And for the "fixtures to use a completely different system" I don't understand. What do you mean?

Comment: Why not dump the database, and import that dump before running tests? That's what you call fixtures

Comment: Because my clients are using the db during the tests and if I do a rollback by backup I will lose the new records (or data)

Comment: If the database you want to use during a test is also used by your clients, then you should use **a different database**

Comment: Yes you are right but I ask myself if there are some good pratices to use another db and import the data from prod-db

Comment: Using a database for tests that is used by customers at the same time is quite the opposite of "best practise". That's something you want to avoid at all costs

Comment: ok. But I don't wish to clone all prod db on pre-prod db. Are there some algorithmes also heuristic to do it?

Answer (score 1):

[How to export some rows of a mysql table with where clause from a php script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15287295/how-to-export-some-rows-of-a-mysql-table-with-where-clause-from-a-php-script)

There are a few tools that will let you export portions of your data for testing. If you have phpmyadmin, it's even easier, but mysqldump works fine.